# QT socket wait for user input

Tags: qt, sockets, user-input, qtcpsocket

i'm trying to develop a simple server with basic authentication,
i have the following code:

```
socket = new QTcpSocket();
connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()),Qt::DirectConnection);
check_user();
```

.......
and check_user() is

```
socket->write("Please enter username:");
socket->flush();
QStringList list;
while (socket->canReadLine())
{
    QString data = QString(socket->readLine());
    if ( data == "\r\n" )
        break;
    list.append(data);
}
qDebug()<<list;
```

but this don't wait for user input and go further.
I would like that this function wait for user input for a string of variable lenght till carriage return.
but how?

Comment: I have done it in my simple project: https://github.com/bogdyname/Freechat/blob/master/Freechat/Network/peerout.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a slot to the `readyRead()` signal of the socket and handle the input there.
(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead)
But for that to work you will need an event loop running in the thread the socket lives in.
(https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html)

Another solution would be to use `waitForReadyRead(-1)` of the socket. This would block the thread and emit the `readyRead()` signal. The function will return `true` if the signal gets emitted. But you would also need a running event loop.
(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead)

Comment: i add socket->waitForReadyRead(-1) in the while loop but doesn't block.
and qstringlist grows with empty characters

Comment: Do you have a running event loop in the thread the socket lives in and a slot connected to the `readyRead()` signal?

Comment: yes i have exec(); and connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);

Comment: Now basically what you will have to do is to call `readLine()` of the socket inside the slot that is connected to the `readyRead()` signal of the socket and handle the data that you read.

Comment: modified this way seems to work

socket->write("Please enter username:");
socket->flush();
QString data;
forever{
    socket->waitForReadyRead(15000);
    data = QString(socket->readLine());
    if ( data.endsWith("\r\n"))
        break;
}
qDebug()<<"received:"<<data;

Comment: This will work unless the socket has no data to be read. Then the `waitForReadyRead()` function will block the thread the socket lives in. If this is not a breaker for your case you can go with this.

Comment: You're setting the timout of the `waitForReadyRead()` to 15 secs. If there is no data ready after 15 secs the function will return and you won't get any data from the `readLine()`. Meaning this will lead to empty results being passed into the debug output. Might want to set the timeout to `-1` so it doesn't timeout.

Comment: got it
    if (socket->waitForReadyRead(15000))
    {
        data = QString(socket->readLine());
    }
    else
        return 4;
    user=data.trimmed();
    qDebug()<<"User:"<<user<<"is logging in";

Comment: Would be nice of you to mark the answer as best answer, so that people know this is a solution if they encounter the same problem.